# Is it possible to make partial workspaces with the PlasticSCM Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, plasticscm

Since our SCM projects are usually quite large, I'd like to only "clone" what's necessary to perform an automated build of a project from within Jenkins. The commandline interface to PlasticSCM, allows the creation of partial workspaces with `cm partial`. Is this also possible using the Jenkins plugin? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the Jenkins plugin doesn't use partial workspaces but regular ones.

- If you enable the "Use update" setting, Jenkins will not delete the workspace at the end of each build and the full update will only be performed the first time.
- Also, you could create your own "cloaked.conf" entering custom rules to avoid downloading the full branch content. This way, you can also select the files to download in a regular workspace. But this is not directly handled by the Jenkins plugin.
  https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide.shtml#ColumnsintheWorkspaceExplorer

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `cloaked.conf` settings. That would fit my need perfectly! The primary reasoning behind my question was that I need to have multiple workspaces of the same respository and I would like to reduce the amount of duplicate data to a minimum.